# Why is such sum of cosines always zero?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, symmetry

[INTRO]

In such arrangement of identical charged particles named $P_1$, $P_2$, ..., $P_n$ (In this diagram $n=5$), the electric field in the center is always zero.

[image: arrangement]

The electric field is given by this equation:

$$\vec F=k\frac{q}{r^2}\hat r$$

Where $\hat r$ points to the radial direction.

If $2|n$, then the forces are obvious canceled by symetry.

If $n$ is odd, again the components of forces in the $y$ axis cancel by symetry. But for the $x$ direction the components cancel if this condition is true:

$$\sum_{c=0}^{n-1}\cos(c \theta)=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \theta=\frac{2\pi}n$$

[END OF INTRO]

My main problem is to prove for any $n$, this relation holds:

$$\sum_{c=0}^{n-1}\cos(2\pi \frac{c}{n})=0$$

Comment: Hint: the real part of a finite geometric series.

Comment: Write it in terms of complex exponential and use the finite geometric series formula.

Comment: @Ian $e^{\theta i}$ you mean? I am not much familiar with complex world.

Comment: Intuitively, if all of those radii are vectors, they cancel out and equal the zero vector. That means that, not only do the vertical components cancel (which is easy to see independently, because $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$), but so do the horizontal components.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Of course! But one will have to merge that intuition with a proof if he wants to make sure that the intuition is right.

Comment: I wasn't arguing against proof-writing, @AHB. Another perspective is that of symmetry: If there is a net pull in any direction, then by rotating our coordinates repeatedly through an angle of $\theta$, that net pull should be in each of 5 different directions!

Comment: @JMoravitz I think this question is more likely to be in the search queue than that one is. It also includes geometrical and physical uses.

Comment: @AHB That one is already half a year old, has a nearly a dozen upvoted answers, and a large number of views already and successfully answers your underlying question.  If you think it does not fully answer your question, then please specify why not so that we may fill that gap in understanding.

Comment: @JMoravitz hmmm. Yeah your right. I guessed such a question must have been asked before. I just couldn't find the keyword to search. Then mark as duplicate or delete?

Comment: @AHB It is certainly difficult sometimes to search for and find duplicates from some time ago.  That is one of the benefits from being active for so long on the site, we can sometimes remember duplicates manually (*as was the case for me here, I know I answered this in the past and could check my own history*).  If you are confident that your phrasing of the question could be more frequently searched, then it may indeed be helpful to leave it up as duplicate for other users to find the linked question.  Otherwise, if your only goal was the answer deletion is fine too.  I leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz for having found this very pertinent reference.

Comment: The force $F_1$ at the orgin exerted by $P_1$ is horizontal and makes an angle of $\pi$ with respect to the positive axis. Add to that the force $F_2$ exerted by $P_2,$ which has the same magnitude but makes an angle of $\pi+2\pi/5$ with respect to the positive axis. Keep going. Adding $F_1 + \cdots +F_5$ as vectors of course means starting with $F_1$ pointing from at $0,$ starting $F_2$ at the end of $F_1,$ etc. What you'll see is that the vector sum leads you around the perimeter of a regular pentagon. We started at $0,$ and we have to end at $0!$

Comment: Do you agree that the total force at the center should be independent of the orientation of this arrangement of charges? If so, then it must be the case that the $x$-components cancel since you can swap the roles of the $x$- and $y$- axes without changing the total charge.

Comment: @amd That is an easily understood non-mathematical proof. Proof by contradiction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid for any regular polygon. It can be viewed physically:

Sum of cosines or sines of equi-spaced *forces* is zero by finding resultant  using a statics force polygon vector diagram.

Or mathematically:

Formula for sum of $n$ equi-spaced ( interval $\alpha , \alpha  = 2 \pi/n $) sines. It can be derived by summing terms from De Moivre's theorem as a geometric progression. 
$$ \frac { \sin n \alpha/2}{ \sin \alpha/2}\cdot  \sin ( average\, angle) $$

Sum of $n$ equi-spaced ( interval $\alpha $) cosines

$$ \frac { \sin n \alpha/2}{ \sin \alpha/2}\cdot  \cos ( average\, angle) $$

Quantity in numerator is $ \sin n \pi $ that vanishes